# Stability of a real matrix and sign changes

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, stability-theory

**Question**: Given a stable $n\times n$ real matrix (namely, all the eigenvalues have strictly negative real part), am I guaranteed that by changing the sign of $i<n$ rows, the matrix will become unstable?

This is clearly true for some cases, e.g., the identity matrix. However, I am wondering if it holds for any matrix with the above properties.

Comment: If the matrix is diagonally dominant, then yes due to gerschgorin

Comment: Also, due to the determinant changing sign, it is true for any $2\times 2$ matrices